# Is it possible to use the Slugger interface other than in a constructor?

Tags: string, symfony, slug

I'm looking to use the sluggerInterface in a class. But I want to keep:

```
public function __construct()
    {
    }
```

So I want to use sluggerInterface in my class without adding any argument in my constructor. (this is in order to automatically create 1 slug when creating an object).

So I want a code different from this one:

```
use Symfony\Component\String\Slugger\SluggerInterface;

    class MyService
    {
        private $slugger;
    
        public function __construct(SluggerInterface $slugger)
        {
            $this->slugger = $slugger;
        }
    
        public function someMethod()
        {
            $slug = $this->slugger->slug('...');
        }
    }
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not want to use autowiring in your constructor ?

You could just create a new slugger, for example with `Symfony\Component\String\Slugger\AsciiSlugger;`

```
$slugger = new AsciiSlugger();
$slugger->slug('Please slug this.')->toString();
```

Or you could also use [autowiring with another method](https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/service_container/autowiring.html#autowiring-other-methods-e-g-setters-and-public-typed-properties) using `@required` annotation (or attribute `#[Required]` for PHP 8+)

```
private $slugger;

#[Required]
public function setSlugger(SluggerInterface $slugger): void
{
    $this->slugger= $slugger;
}
```

> this is in order to automatically create 1 slug when creating an object

You may also want to look into event listener, using doctrine event `prePersist` to slug your entity when persisted could be another idea.

Finally, [gedmo doctrine-extensions sluggable](https://github.com/doctrine-extensions/DoctrineExtensions/blob/main/doc/sluggable.md) may interest you as well.

Comment: Hi I used GEDMO but it doesn't respond as I want:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74632615/how-to-avoid-changing-the-slug-with-gedmo