# How to avoid changing the slug with GEDMO?

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

I use GEDMO for my symfony application.

I set up the updatedAt like this:

```
#[ORM\Column(nullable: true)]
     /**
     * @var \DateTimeImmutable $updatedAt
     * 
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
     */
    private ?\DateTimeImmutable $updatedAt = null;
```

I'm surprised that when loading my fistures, the updatedAt fills automatically (instead of only filling when there is an update)

But my problem is with the slug. I put this:

```
 #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    /**
     * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"id", "nom"})
     */
    private $slug;
```

However in EasyAdmin, as soon as I change the 'name' field and save, it automatically changes the slug. Except that's precisely what I don't want

In Easyadmin:

```
TextField::new('slug')->hideOnForm(),
```

I know there is the slugField for easyadmin, but I don't use in itnerface easyadmin.

maybe I made a mistake somewhere?

My wish:
When I change the name field, the slug is identical to the previous one, unless I ask him to do so in easyadmin, but during a creation I cannot put the SlugField field because I removed the setSlug.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

There is an option to prevent your slug from updating.

> `updatable` (optional, default=true) - true to update the slug on sluggable field changes, false - otherwise

So you could change your slug configuration with:

```
#[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
/**
 * @Gedmo\Slug(updatable=false, fields={"id", "nom"})
 */
private $slug;
```

[Some other configuration options for slug annotation and attribute:](https://github.com/doctrine-extensions/DoctrineExtensions/blob/main/doc/sluggable.md)

```
fields (required, default=[]) - list of fields for slug
updatable (optional, default=true) - true to update the slug on sluggable field changes, false - otherwise
unique (optional, default=true) - true if slug should be unique and if identical it will be suffixed, false - otherwise
unique_base (optional, default=null) - used in conjunction with unique. The name of the entity property that should be used as a key when doing a uniqueness check.
separator (optional, default="-") - separator which will separate words in slug
prefix (optional, default="") - prefix which will be added to the generated slug
suffix (optional, default="") - suffix which will be added to the generated slug
style (optional, default="default") - "default" all letters will be lowercase, "camel" - first word letter will be uppercase, "upper"- all word letter will be uppercase and "lower"- all word letter will be lowercase
handlers (only available in annotations, optional, default=[]) - list of slug handlers, like tree path slug, or customized, for example see bellow
```

Comment: Thanks, but that only partially answers. During an update it therefore does not change the slug, except that I wish to be able to change it from easyadmin with the SlugField

Comment: I tried the events but I can't...

Comment: I don't understand, you want a slug that does not update but can be updated manually ? What does not work if you make a slug updatable=false and add a slug field in your form ?

Comment: I wish that: during an addition gedmo manufactures the slug (ok it works) I wish during an update that gedmo does nothing (ok it works). But I also want to be able to change the slug on easyadmin whenever I want (it doesn't work it doesn't update anything)

Comment: during an insert => gedmo / during an update gedmo does nothing, but I want to be able to change the slug manually on easyadmin

Comment: using updatable=false when modifying the fields gedmo does not update (so ok) but in easyadmin (with SlugField or TestField) the update on the slug does not work